# how to fade-out/blur div's borders with css?

Tags: html, css

I have read a lot of topic about this problem but nothing has worked so far.
the easiest method I have read about involves using box-shadow, but this results in the shadow having a different color to the box even though the code of the color is the same (#141414).

**Question**

How can I get a fade-out/blur border for a div box? It's quite hard to explain in writing so I made this image to give you the idea (ignore the background). If you **look closely** you can see the blending and the color is uniform, fading to transparent.

[image]
box-shadow as i said, doesn't work for me.

```css
body {
  background-image:url('http://phptesting.altervista.org/tessuto.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
    background-color: #141414;
    border: 2px solid #141414;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #141414;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your image is just a black box? Also, look into gradients for borders?

Comment: @Robypelle next time please work harder on the grammar... also you can click on the button that looks like a mountain under the sun in order to embed your image within the question...

Comment: @slime look closely....

Comment: @hello_there_andy sorry i'm not mother language and i'm still learning. for the image i tried to put it as an attachment (but i couldn't because i had only 1 reputation)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`box-shadow` IS actually the only CSS way to get this effect. Try something like this:

```css
div {
  margin: 25px 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #141414;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #141414;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

changes the color with fade effect

```css
#yourIDhere:hover{
    transition-property: border-color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    border-color: #976958;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fade a border using Styled Components. It is based on https://styled-components.com/docs/api

Other answers provided a way to animate the component but I just wanted to fade the border, not the component. After playing with it I realized that I just have to specify the border attribute.

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const fadeOut = keyframes`
    0% { border: 2px solid blue; };
    100% { border: 2px solid white; };
`

const MyStyle = styled.div`
    animation: ${fadeOut} ease 3s;
    transition-property: border-color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).